# Remove every occurence of the number 13 and the next number from a list, then sum the result

Tags: python

This function takes a list, deletes every occurrence of the number 13 *and* deletes the number present after 13 in every instance and then prints the sum of the list.

How can I shorten it?

```
def average(nums):
  thirteen_idx = []
  bad_idx = []
  final_list = []
  num_length = len(nums)-1

  #list of indexes where 13 resides
  for i in range(len(nums)):
    if nums[i] == 13:
      thirteen_idx.append(i)

  #make list of indexes where 13 resides and the index after it (bad_idx)
  for i in range(len(thirteen_idx)):
    bad_idx.append(thirteen_idx[i])
    bad_idx.append(thirteen_idx[i]+1)

  #delete any index from bad_idx that is greater than the highest index in nums
    if bad_idx[-1] > num_length:
        bad_idx.pop(len(bad_idx)-1)

  #we now have a list of all bad indexes (bad_idx)

  #iterate thru nums and move any non bad index into a final_list
  for i in range(len(nums)):
    if i not in bad_idx:
      final_list.append(nums[i])

  print (sum(final_list))
```

Comment: What is the result wanted for `[13, 13, 1]`?

Comment: @greybeard: the code, as posted, produces `0` for that.

Answer (score 6):

Your output is simply a sum of certain numbers. You don't need to build intermediary lists at all here, just *select the numbers you want to sum*, by looping. Your criteria are that the *current* number should not be 13, and the *preceding* number should not be 13.

To achieve this, you could just use a loop that remembers the preceding number:

- initialize a `preceding` variable to a value you can easily test for. Here, any value other than 13 would do, and `None` is probably a good sentinel value.
- In a loop over the numbers, if the *current* number is not 13 *and* the *preceding* number is not 13, add it to the running total.
- At the end of the loop, set `preceding` to the current number. That way, when you go back to the top of the loop body, `preceding` will still contain the number from the preceding iteration.

So, given an input of `[17, 13, 3, 9]`, you'd want to sum the first and the last number. We start with `preceding` set to `None`, `result` is set to `0` and we iterate 4 times:

1. `preceding = None`, set `current` to the first value `17`.

   - `preceding != 13 and current != 13` is *true*, so add the current value to the result -> `result = 0 + 17 = 17`.
   - set `preceding = current`, so `17`
2. `preceding = 17`, set `current` to the second value `13`.

   - `preceding != 13 and current != 13` is **false** (`current` is set to 13), so *skip* this value.
   - set `preceding = current`, so `13`
3. `preceding = 13`, set `current` to the third value `3`.

   - `preceding != 13 and current != 13` is **false** (`preceding` is set to 13), so *skip* this value.
   - set `preceding = current`, so `3`
4. `preceding = 3`, set `current` to the forth value `9`.

   - `preceding != 13 and current != 13` is *true*, so add the current value to the result -> `result = 17 + 9 = 26`.
   - set `preceding = current`, so `9`

and you end up with `result = 26`.

Generally speaking, when you find yourself wanting to look *ahead* in a `for` loop, turn the problem around and look *behind* instead. It is *much simpler*, as your loop will already have processed the items behind.

Translating those steps above to Python code looks like this:

```
def sum_without_13s(nums):
    """Sum all values that are not equal to 13 or directly follow 13"""

    # the running total of qualifying numbers
    result = 0
    # the preceding value in the loop, set at the end of the loop body
    preceding = None  # any value that is not 13 would do

    for value in nums:
        # only add to the sum if this value and the preceding value are both
        # *not* equal to 13.
        if value != 13 and preceding != 13:
            result += value

        # for the next iteration, remember the current value so we can
        # skip any values that followed 13.
        preceding = value

    return result
```

That's the most *readable* method of implementing your algorithm. The function produces the sum of integers not 13, and not directly following 13:

```
>>> sum_without_13s([13, 99, 3])  # only 3 fits criteria, so should produce 3
3
>>> sum_without_13s([99, 3])  # no 13s, so sum should be 102
102
>>> sum_without_13s([1, 2, 13, 13, 3, 4])  # only 1, 2, and 4 should be summed == 7
7
```

Note that the function also *returns* the result, rather than print the result to the console. If you want to see the output of your function, you can always print the returned value:

```
>>> theanswer = sum_without_13s([17, 13, 19, 18, 13, 13, 3, 7])
>>> print(theanswer)
42
```

### Other looping constructs that give you access to the preceding value

You could in principle make use of [`itertools.chain()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to produce an iterator of `(preceding, current)` tuples to loop over, and so make it possible to filter and sum in a generator expression.

The above 'preceding value' approach is a variant of the [`pairwise()` function from the `itertools` recipes section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes). But where `pairwise()` starts with `(nums[0], nums[1])` and ends at `(nums[-2], nums[-1])`,  we really need to be starting with `(None, nums[0])` *first* because we wouldn't want to skip either the first or the last value in your input from consideration.

So here's a `with_preceding()` function, with a configurable default value for that first element of the first tuple:

```
from itertools import chain, tee

def with_preceding(iterable, default=None):
    "s -> (default, s0), (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    return zip(chain((default,), a), b)
```

which then can be used in an alternate implementation using a generator expression, like this:

```
def sum_without_13s_iter(nums):
    """Sum all values that are not equal to 13 or directly follow 13"""
    return sum(
        current
        for preceding, current in with_preceding(nums)
        if preceding != 13 and current != 13
    )
```

However, readability suffers, in my eyes, and for little gain as the above is actually *slower* than the first version. See the small benchmark at the very end.

### Performance considerations

I tried to construct what I hoped would be a *faster* function using iterators, the `itertools` and `operator` modules and the `sum()`, `map()` and `zip()` functions to try and avoid the Python interpreter loop altogether, but this was simply not any faster; at best I could get it to be about 5-10% *slower* than the above first version of the function.

If performance *is* a concern, then you should really be using numpy arrays anyway. With a numpy array of integers as the input, the function can be expressed as:

```
import numpy as np

def array_sum_without_13s(numarray):
    """Sum all values in an array that are not equal to 13 or directly follow 13"""
    # boolean array with True where the input array has 13
    is13 = numarray == 13
    # boolean array with True where the input array is preceded by 13
    follows13 = np.concatenate(([False], is13[:-1]))
    # sum of all values that don't fit either of the above criteria
    return np.sum(numarray[~(is13 | follows13)])
```

As stated, this function expects a numpy array as the input:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> array_sum_without_13s(np.array([13, 99, 3]))
3
>>> array_sum_without_13s(np.array([99, 3]))
102
>>> array_sum_without_13s(np.array([1, 2, 13, 13, 3, 4]))
7
>>> array_sum_without_13s(np.array([17, 13, 19, 18, 13, 13, 3, 7]))
42
```

Given an input of 1 million integers, the numpy version takes ~3.5 milliseconds versus the pure-Python version taking ~89 milliseconds. Numpy is the numeric processing champion, hands down:

```py
In [1]: import random
   ...: import numpy as np
   ...: from codereview237899 import sum_without_13s, array_sum_without_13s
   ...: testdata = random.choices(range(1_000), k=1_000_000)
   ...: testarray = np.array(testdata)
   ...:

In [2]: %timeit sum_without_13s(testdata)
88.7 ms ± 2.12 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [3]: %timeit array_sum_without_13s(testarray)
3.55 ms ± 81.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [4]: %timeit sum_without_13s_iter(testdata)
119 ms ± 13.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

The last test there is for the `with_preceding()` and generator expression variant above; it's a disappointing 35% slower.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative, **if you don't need the filtered list later on**, is to iterate over and sum only the numbers you want:

```
def myfunc(l): 
     it = iter(l) 
     total = 0 
     try: 
         for i in it: 
             if i == 13: 
                 next(it)  # skip the number following a '13'
             else: 
                 total += i 
         return total 
     except StopIteration: 
         return total
```

The trick here is to transform the list into an iterator to make use of the `next()` function to easily skip the value following a `13`.

Using the list `[13,99,3]`:

When using the iterator in the for-loop what it does is, at the beginning of each loop it will take the next value in the iterator and place it into the variable `i`. When we use the `next(i)` we say to the iterator "give me the next value please" but we don't do anything with it, so at the next loop the iterator will give us again the next value.

It may not be clear so here's an example with the list`[13,99,3]`:

- `it` is an iterator which state is "13 then 99 then 3" at the beginning
- 1st loop: we ask for the next value in `it`: we get `13`. The iterator state is now "99 then 3"

  - since `i == 13` we ask for the next value (`next(it)`), it gives us `99` (but we don't do anything with it as you can see) the state of the iterator is now "3"
- 2nd loop: we ask for the next value in `it` (which state is "3" according to the previous point): so we get `3`. The state of the iterator is now empty.

  - since `3 !== 13` we add it to the `total`.
- The iterator is empty so we quit the loop and return the total

But, as you can see, if 13 is the last element in the iterator when we'll ask for the `next(it)` it will raise an error, this is why we use the `try/except` block, because we now that the end of an iteration is indicated by an exception ([doc here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types)).

Comment: Does this handle `1, 2, 13, 13, 3, 4` correctly?  I.e. `1, 2, 3, 4` or `1, 2, 4`?

Comment: I believe this code is wrong; I'd expect `1, 2, 13, 13, 3, 4` to sum to *7*, but your code produces *10*. The code in the question produces 7 for that input.

Comment: I believe you could fix that problem by adding a `while i == 13: i = next(it)` loop inside the `if` branch, but I can't say I'm fond of the iterator approach to this problem at the moment.

Comment: Other nitpicks: your function body is indented 5 spaces rather than 4, and you have a redundant `return total` both in the `try:` and in the `except StopIteration:` blocks. Just put a single `return total` at the end of the function (outside of the `try...except` statement) and use `pass` in the except handler.

Answer (score 2):

if you just wanna filter 13 from the list of entries then you can do something like this

```py
l = [1,2,13,14,13,12,14,12,13]
filtered_list = list(filter(lambda x: x!= 13, l))
print(sum(filtered_list)
```

Further your requirement is not clear, can you elaborate this part *"and deletes the number after the 13x"* a bit more?

Ok Here is the code I suggest, have a look at this:

```py
def get_zipped_list(given_list):
    # return list(zip(given_list, list(filter(lambda x: x != 13, given_list))))
    return list(zip(given_list, given_list[1:]))


def sum_excluding_13_and_following(given_list):
    length = len(given_list)
    if 0 < length <= 2:
        return sum(filter(lambda x: x != 13, given_list))
    elif all(x == 13 for x in given_list):
        return 0
    elif length >= 3:
        zipped_list = get_zipped_list(given_list)
        pairs_with_13_as_leading_elem = list(filter(lambda x: x[0] == 13, zipped_list))
        if given_list[-1] == 13:
            del given_list[-1]
        return sum(given_list) - sum([sum(x) for x in zip(*pairs_with_13_as_leading_elem)])
    else:
        return 0


list_1 = [1, 2, 13, 14, 13, 12, 14, 12, 13]
list_2 = [13, 1, 2, 13, 14, 13, 12, 14, 12, 13]
list_3 = [1, 2, 13, 14, 13, 12, 14, 12]

small_ls_1 = [1, 13]
small_ls_2 = [13, 10]
small_ls_3 = [13, 13]

all_13s = [13, 13, 13, 13]

print(sum_excluding_13_and_following(all_13s))
print(sum_excluding_13_and_following(small_ls_1))
print(sum_excluding_13_and_following(small_ls_2))
print(sum_excluding_13_and_following(small_ls_3))
print(sum_excluding_13_and_following(list_1))
print(sum_excluding_13_and_following(list_2))
```

Comment: Trying to get the sum of a list of numbers. The only catch is not to count the number 13 or the next number in the list after 13. Example: if the list was (1, 13, 6, 8, 9, 13) you would not include the first 13, the number after it, 6, or the last 13 (there is no number after the last 13 to omit, this caused me many problems with index out of range errors)

Comment: Instead of removing why don't you simply sum the numbers you don't want and then substract it from the total of the list ? In your example that would be `(1+13+6+8+9+13) - (13+6+13)`. *If you don't need the filtered list later* then there's no point in filtering it when you can just do maths

Comment: he can simply remove the 13's or the count of 13's but the only issue might be with the follow up number which also should be skipped

Comment: @jra updated my post with some code and test samples, please check if that works for you, I can add some comments in for better readability if you want

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of things you can do.

1. Don't use an additional list `bad_idx` and do everything using the list `nums`.
2. When you find the index of each of the 13s in the first for loop, delete the 
    value there itself by using:

   ```
   nums.remove(13)
   ```

   or

   ```
   nums.pop(i)
   ```
3. After removing 13s, remove the value next to the 13s by using:

   ```
   nums.pop(i+1)
   ```

By doing all this you aren't using 2 additional lists `bad_idx` and `final_list`, plus you are looping 2 fewer times.

Comment: What if 13 is the last number in the list, then i+1 is index out of range.

Comment: Easy! add a conditional statement before deleting the number next to 13 like this: if i!=(len(lis)-1): and then include the line to delete the number

Comment: Once you removed the 13s, the values directly after will be at position `i`, **not** position `i + 1`, as all the following items in the list will have shifted up a position! For the same reason,  you don't want to iterate over a list and remove items at the same time, unless you plan to iterate *from the end*. Iteration will not account for the updated indices and will easily lead to bugs.

Comment: Given an input sequence of size N, it doesn't matter all that much if you are then using 1, 2 or 3 sequential loops over the input lists. If more loops make code easier to read, just use more loops. All you are doing is perhaps increase the fixed cost per iteration.